# Javascript indentation in VIM

Tags: javascript, vim, indentation, auto-indent

I'm trying to get VIM to indent Javascript with the '=' and related commands. When I try to auto indent the following, for example:

```
   new function($) {
     $.fn.setCursorPosition = function(pos) { 
       if ($(this).setSelectionRange) {
         $(this).setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
       } else if ($(this).createTextRange) {
         var range = $(this).createTextRange();
         range.collapse(true);
         range.moveEnd('character', pos);
         range.moveStart('character', pos);
         range.select();
       }
```

The result is the rather absurd:

```
       new function($) {
       $.fn.setCursorPosition = function(pos) {
       if ($(this).setSelectionRange) {
       $(this).setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
       } else if ($(this).createTextRange) {
       var range = $(this).createTextRange();
       range.collapse(true);
       range.moveEnd('character', pos);
       range.moveStart('character', pos);
       range.select();
       }
```

I've set `set syntax=javascript`, and I've set `filetype` to:

```
filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:ON
```

Though I've tried every permutation of this. I've tried every permutation of `smartindent`, `autoindent`, and `cindent`, but nothing seems to have the correct effect of giving Vim the expected indentation. I've set `tabstop=4`.

I've installed [`javascript.vim`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1840), and [`IndentAnything`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1839), though they don't seem to have any effect.

I'd be very grateful for any suggestions as to how to get Vim indenting properly in JavaScript.

Comment: Side note: Installing javascript.vim and IndentAnything solved a problem for me where vim was only indenting some of the lines correctly.

Answer (score 12):

Oh man, I just spent a couple of hours figuring out the same problem.

If you have `filetype indent on` (which you do), then a few different indent settings may be set by a file somewhere. If you use `verbose set <option>?` you can see where it's being set and what it's set to:

```
:verbose set autoindent?
:verbose set cindent?
:verbose set smartindent?
:verbose set indentexpr?
```

By default, you'd only expect to see `cindent` set by the default indent file:

```
cindent
Last set from $VIMRUNTIME/indent/javascript.vim
```

Where `$VIMRUNTIME` is the path you get when you run `:echo $VIMRUNTIME`.

All of the others wouldn't be set unless you enable them (in your vimrc or a plugin).

For me, I had a plugin (eclim) that was setting `identexpr` and causing this issue:

```
identexpr=EclimGetJavascriptIndent(V:lnum)
Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/eclim/indent/javascript.vim
```

Comment: Thanks for this! You helped me locate a buggy plugin as well. :)

Comment: Wow, thank you. You just helped me debug an inexplicably broken vim. It would not autoindent in JS files. It turned out to be a bundle at `.vim/bundle/vim-jsx` (which I just had to remove, since I just switched to https://github.com/othree/yajs.vim anyway).

Thanks. I want to buy you a beer, if the opportunity ever presents itself.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem some time ago and the solution was the plugin "vim-javascript". It is JavaScript bundle for vim providing syntax and indent plugins.

https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript

The installation is very simple.

If you are using **[pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen)**, use the follow steps:

```
  cd ~/.vim/bundle
  git clone https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript.git
```

If you are using **vundle** use the follow steps:

Add the follow line to your vimrc file:

```
Plugin "pangloss/vim-javascript"
```

And install it:

```
:so ~/.vimrc
:PluginInstall
```

Comment: This plugin works really well. FWIW, I was having a problem despite having this plugin installed, and because another plugin (vim-polyglot) was superceding it and causing problems. So if anyone still has problems after installing this, spot-check your other plugins

Answer (score 4):

Adding the two closing braces and selecting the entire block with `vi{` provided proper automatic indentation for me in gvim 7.2 with no plugins. You may want to see if an errant plugin is messing it up by starting vim with the `--noplugins` flag on the command line. and try again.

Answer (score 3):

I hate to say something unhelpful like "It works for me", but it does. Even with nothing in my .vimrc and all plugins off, I get the correct indentation.

```
new function($) {
    $.fn.setCursorPosition = function(pos) { 
        if ($(this).setSelectionRange) {
            $(this).setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
        } else if ($(this).createTextRange) {
            var range = $(this).createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', pos);
            range.moveStart('character', pos);
            range.select();
        }
```

Have you tried loading vim with the `--noplugins` switch and temporarily moving/renaming your .vimrc to see if it still doesn't work? I suspect another setting in your .vimrc or another plugin may be causing the conflict.

Answer (score 3):

For me it works (not very helpful statement, I know ;-) ).
I suppose that the filetype is not detected correctly.

What does

```
 :set filetype
```

say? It should report "javascript".

[EDIT]
Hint: Please note that there is an option called 'filetype' and a command called :filetype.
To get help for the option do :help 'filetype' for the command do :help :filetype.

Comment: @Habi: Thanks. It'd be a shame to have missed that, but alas `:set filetype` is `javascript`. :)

Comment: @Brian M. Hunt: Hmmm, maybe the indentation is 0 (I don't know if this is possible at all, but if it is possible it could be a reason for your problem). What does ":set shiftwidth" and ":set cinoptions" say?

Comment: @Habi: `:set shiftwidth` is `shiftwidth=4` and `set cinoptions` is `cinoptions=`. hrmm.

Comment: @Brian M. Hunt: Same here. Strange. Does the '=' work for other languages, for example C?

Comment: @Brian M. Hunt: Another idea: What does ':set equalprg" say? Its value should be "" by default.

Comment: Aye, it's `:set equalprg` returns `equalprg=`.

Answer (score 3):

I was having problems the other day with MacVim 7.2 and a Lua file that wouldn't indent correctly -- even after using `set syntax`, `set filetype` and `filetype indent on`, it wasn't indenting the file correctly.

I discovered adding:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

to my `.gvimrc` file solved the issue, at least for me. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for the reply & glad you solved this. Unfortunately this didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to indent without using any plugin.

- Switch to Normal by hitting ESC key.
- Type `gg=G`

What is does is: `gg` moves the cursor to the top of the file, `=` will trigger auto-indentation, `G` will move the cursor to the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

For me the presence of more than one '(' character before the '{' character on the same line seemed to change the indentation algorithm used by '='. Removing one of the '(' seemed to fix '=' for all parts of the file except other scope regions '{...}' which also had multiple '(' on the opening line.

I'm using vim 7.4 in lubuntu