# How can I have Vim get this JS indenting right?

Tags: javascript, vim, indentation, auto-indent

Emacs user here, giving Vim a go. :)

I like the quick keystrokes and the overall philosphy very much, but I've been hitting some trouble with the slightly more advanced stuff. One of my gripes is indenting (using the `=` command).

See this JS snippet. This is how Emacs' js2-mode indents it. I like this :

```
var MyClass = declare([], {
    constructor: function(params) {
        if(!params) {
            params = {};
        }
```

Now this is what Vim does with it. Friggin' hell :

```
       var MyClass = declare([], {
constructor: function(params) {
if(!params) {
params = {};
}
```

All the code above this construction gets indented decently, but from there on it simply sucks. And I have this kind of construction a bit all over my code. I've checked `:filetype` and flipped those switches on. I've tried with and without plugins. Not getting it right. Vim is gVim 7.4, downloaded a couple of days ago. I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223695/javascript-indentation-in-vim) and the snippet shown there is indented correctly out of the box.

Does anybody have a clue what I could attempt here ?
Thanks for any advice !

Comment: Did you set paste (:set paste)? Because that will do it to you if you have that configured.  Also, you'll know that you do when you're in insert mode and it says "-- INSERT (paste) --" instead of just "-- INSERT --".  To take it off, type ":set nopaste" (if it's configured).

Comment: Hi ! No, I have a regular insert prompt. I'm now just trying out the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.vimrc`:

```
set  nocompatible " vi is decades old

set expandtab     " use soft tabs set shiftwidth=2  # 2 spaces tabs for JS (?) set softtabstop=2

filetype on 
filetype plugin on 
filetype plugin indent on " auto indent for supported languages (JS included)
```

To reformat all the file, type `gg=G`

```
gg -> go to top of file
= -> indent 
G -> until the end of the file
```

Comment: This seems to work. Thanks ! I get other uglinesses now though, and Vim does not seem to care much for my `set softtabstop=4 tabstop=4`. Time to try out the plugin above !

Comment: You only need `filetype plugin indent on` the other filetype lines are redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I've been a VIM user for > 10 years and I'm using [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1491) Javascript syntax plugin. I've tested indentation by

1: creating a new file and setting the filetype

```
:set filetype=javascript
```

2: Pasting your (malformatted) code

3: Hitting gg=G (which formats the complete buffer)

The resulting code looks good for me:

```
var MyClass = declare([], {
  constructor: function(params) {
    if(!params) {
      params = {};
    }
```

Comment: This gives me a different syntax highlighting, but does not seem to help with indentation though.

Comment: I found that this package gives nearly satisfactory indenting :) https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript